# How do I trigger firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, triggers

```
<div class="namaz" id="zora">Zora: </div>
<div class="namaz" id="izlazak">Izlazak sunca: </div>
<div class="namaz" id="podne">Podne: </div>
<div class="namaz" id="ikindija">Ikindija: </div>
<div class="namaz" id="aksam">Akšam: </div>
<div class="namaz"id="jacija" >Jacija: </div>
```

Inside of these div's there's a time (eg 15:36) that I withdrew from a certain API, how do I send a trigger to the firebase database using javascript that will change just one variable when the time is equal to that one in the div?

```
function fetchData() {
    fetch("https://api.vaktija.ba/")
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        const arr = data.vakat;
        const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("namaz");
        Array.from(elements).forEach((element, index) => {
           element.innerText = `${element.innerText} ${arr[index]}`;
        })
        
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

This is a function I'm using for getting the data from the API and placing it inside of the div's.

```
cool-vaktija-default-rtdb
     aktivno: "nije"
```

This is the variable value. From "nije" to "jest" or something else.

https://cool-vaktija-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/

And the link for it.

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database is quite well [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and there are a lot of great tutorials out there. Did you try anything yet? If not, I recommend starting with the docs and tutorials.

Comment: I did, not that successful tho. I have to make just a simple IoT project with just one function that triggers Arduino.
Can you suggest to me any good free courses to start studying those things?